# Externalize Credentials from Flat Java

Tags: java, external, config, credentials, hardcoded

I have a flat java file that's querying two databases and currently has the credentials hardcoded. The plan is to convert this to spring batch but in the mean time I would like to encrypt them within a config/properties file externally and call them. I'm looking for any specific examples, best practice / solution. I appreciate any time and effort. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to encrypt the credentials, then you have the problem of secure storing the encryption key. The best you can do it to *not* store it at all and require it to be given manually whenever your application starts up. Your application should use the key to decrypt credentials, connect to any services. Finally it must throw away the key and credentials after use, in order to prevent getting them from memory.

If manual intervention during application startup is unacceptable, then a typical solution is storing the key in a file with appropriately restrictive permissions on an encrypted partition, but if the system gets compromised, e.g. an attacker somehow gets root privileges or privileges of your application, he will be able to recover the database credentials.

Comment: Unfortunately manual intervention is unnacceptable. This is only a temporary solution, and I'd prefer to have the credentials stored in a file rather than hardcoded for the meantime. Thank you very much for the input